# HTML Input form error message flickers

Tags: html, css, forms, validation, input

So I created this very simple age gate and when the user is younger then 18 they get an error message "Try Again" at the bottom of the "Verify Age" button. Everything is working correctly but when the "Try Again" message shows it only flickers, shows for one second and disappears.  I want it to stay visible until the user clicks on one of the input boxes.  What am I doing wrong?  If you type in 2010 in the year input box  you can see the "Try Again" message flicker.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style>

    body{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #ageGateWrapper{
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        text-align: center;
        width: 512px;
        height: 288px;
        border: 2px solid #d5882c;
    }

    #innerWrapper{
        position: relative;
        top: 10%;
    }

    h1{
        position: relative;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
    }


    #ageGateWrapper ul{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #ageGateWrapper ul li{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    input {
         padding: 10px;
         width: 100%;
         font-size: 16px;
         font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
         font-weight: 400;
         letter-spacing: 2px;
         color: #ffffff;
         border: 2px solid #d5882c;
         background-color: #000000;
         width: 80px;
         height: 50px;
         text-align: center;
         margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #submit {
        position: relative;
        top: 15px;
        text-align: center; 
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 16;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        width: 135px;
        height: 60px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #000000;
        border: 2px solid #d5882c;
    }


    #errorDiv{
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        top:25px;
        font-size: 16;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

</style>

<script language="javascript">

function age(){
    var validated = false;
    var minimumAge = 18;
    var minYear;
    var bday=parseInt(document.forms[0].txtBday.value);
    var bmo=(parseInt(document.forms[0].txtBmo.value)+1);
    var byr=parseInt(document.forms[0].txtByr.value);
    //var byr;
    var age;
    var now = new Date();
    currentDay=now.getDate();
    currentMo=(now.getMonth()+1);
    currentYr=(now.getFullYear());
    console.log("tday " + currentDay);
    console.log("tmo " + currentMo);
    console.log("tyr " + currentYr);

    minYear = currentYr - minimumAge;




    if(byr > minYear){
        failed();
    }


    if(byr >= minYear){

        if(bmo == currentMo){

            if(bday >= currentDay){
                //alert("PASS");
                passed();
            }

        }else if(bmo < currentMo){
            failed();

        }else if(bmo > currentMo){
                //alert("PASS 2");
                passed();
        }
    }

}



function passed(){
    alert("SHOW CONTENT");
    window.parent.postMessage("teaser ended", '*');
}

function failed(){
    document.getElementById("errorDiv").style.display= "block";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ageGateWrapper">
        <div id="innerWrapper">
        <h1> ENTER YOUR DATE OF BIRTH</h1>
        <form>
        <ul>
            <li><div> <input type="text" name="txtBmo" placeholder="MM"> </div></li>
            <li><div> <input type="text" name="txtBday" size="4" placeholder="DD"> </div></li>
            <li><div> <input type="text" name="txtByr"size="4" placeholder="YYYY"> </div></li>
        <ul>    
            <input type="submit" value="VERIFY AGE" onClick="age()" id="submit">
            <div id="errorDiv">Try Again </di>

        <form>
        </div>  
    </div>      

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent the form from submitting by supplying an event argument and applying the `preventDefault()` method to it:

**html**

```
<input type="submit" value="VERIFY AGE" onClick="age(event)" id="submit">
```

**javascript**

```
function age(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var validated = false;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "try again" is flickering because you have set the "Verify Age" button to "submit" type. Every time you click Verify Age, the browser interprets that as a form submission to the server causing it to refresh and reset the DOM. Changing it to "button" will usually fix this issue.

```
<form>
        <ul>
            <li><div> <input type="text" name="txtBmo" placeholder="MM"> </div></li>
            <li><div> <input type="text" name="txtBday" size="4" placeholder="DD"> </div></li>
            <li><div> <input type="text" name="txtByr"size="4" placeholder="YYYY"> </div></li>
        <ul>    
            <input type="button" value="VERIFY AGE" onClick="age()" id="submit">//BUTTON TYPE
            <div id="errorDiv">Try Again </di>

        <form>
```

Comment: btw.. an Age Validator should not say "try again" if they are not old enough.

Comment: It worked, thanks.  Yeah the "try again" was only dummy text.

Answer (score 0):

Try correcting errors in HTML code.

1) Close `ul`

2) Close `form`

3) Correct `div` closer for error div as well. it is currently `

Give it a try.